# gluon Sequential model: params return empty collection

Tags: python, mxnet

I am using the code below to create a Sequential Gluon model. For some reason the property params returns an empty collection.

```
def build_net():
    net = gluon.nn.Sequential()
    with net.name_scope():
        net.add(gluon.nn.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
        net.add(gluon.nn.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
        net.add(gluon.nn.Dense(1))

    net.collect_params().initialize(mx.init.Normal(sigma=.1))
    return net

net_1 = build_net() 
print(net_1.params)
```

Output:

```
sequential0_ (

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Sequential.collect_params()`, which collects not only this `Block` parameters, but also from all children (e.g. Layers).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`collect_params()`](https://mxnet.apache.org/versions/1.0.0/api/python/gluon/gluon.html#mxnet.gluon.Block.collect_params) to returns a ParameterDict containing this Block and all of its children’s Parameters

```py
def build_net():
    net = gluon.nn.Sequential()
    with net.name_scope():
        net.add(gluon.nn.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
        net.add(gluon.nn.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
        net.add(gluon.nn.Dense(1))

    net.initialize(mx.init.Normal(sigma=.1))
    return net

net_1 = build_net() 
print(net_1.collect_params())
```